# How to deploy a vaadin GAE application?

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, vaadin

I'm developing the first application with vaadin + maven + google app engine.
I already created the maven structure [Using apache maven](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven#building_the_guestbook_demo_using_guestbook-archetype).I created a simple vaadin project and i run it with appengine:devserver. Now , my trouble is that I'm not able to deploy it in Google Cloud.

How can i do?